# The Jhipster generator keeps generate reactive projects and should not

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I use directly a .jdl file in order to generate a microservice project.

I have gateway and three microservices.
My simplified jdl file:

```
application {
  config {
    baseName projectName,
    reactive false, //I tried to enforce this, although I know the default value is already false
    applicationType gateway,
    packageName com.ritan.projectName.gateway,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    clientFramework react,
    buildTool maven,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    searchEngine elasticsearch,
    testFrameworks [cypress],
    serverPort 8085
  }
  
  entities 
  /* from first microservice */
  A, B, C,
  /* from the second microservice */
  D, E,
  /* from the third microservice */
  F, G
}

application {
  config {
    baseName firstMicroservice,
    reactive false,
    applicationType microservice,
    packageName com.ritan.projectName.firstMicroservice,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    searchEngine elasticsearch,
    serverPort 8081
  }
  entities A, B, C 
}

application {
  config {
    baseName secondMicroservice,
    reactive false,
    applicationType microservice,
    packageName com.ritan.projectName.secondMicroservice,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    searchEngine elasticsearch,
    serverPort 8082
  }
  entities D, E
}

application {
  config {
    baseName thirdMicroservice,
    reactive false,
    applicationType microservice,
    packageName com.ritan.projectName.thirdMicroservice,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    searchEngine elasticsearch,
    serverPort 8082
  }
  entities F, G
}

entity A {
 /* some values */ 
}
entity B {
 /* some values */
}
entity C {
 /* some values */
}
entity D {
 /* some values */ 
}
entity E {
 /* some values */ 
}
entity F {
 /* some values */ 
}
entity G {
 /* some values */ 
}

/* Relaitonships */
/* I do not have entities that belong to several microservices. */

microesrvice A, B, C with firstMicroservice
microesrvice D, E with secondMicroservice
microesrvice F, G with thirdMicroservice

paginate A, B, C with pagination
paginate D, E with pagination
paginate F, G with infinite-scroll

service A, B, C, D, E, F, G with serviceClass
search A, B, C, D, E, F, G with elasticsearch
```

References:

- [JDL Options (reactive options is false default)](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/applications)
- [Other jdl projects I've been looking at.](https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples)

And as I said in the title, the code generated is reactive, quite bizare, only the code in the gateway is reactive. Microservices are not reactive.

And one more question, should I have generated code in the gate for communication with the microservices? At the moment I only have a code for communicating with its own database (Jhipster users database).

And if I have to write the code, the connection should be WebClient or something else? As far as I know, RestTemplate can not be use since is blocking and the gate is reactive so non-blocking context.

Jhipster version:

```
jhipster --version
INFO! Using bundled JHipster
7.7.0
```

Comment: The gateway is only reactive since it's based on Spring Cloud Gateway.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou is correct. See https://www.jhipster.tech/2021/03/21/jhipster-release-7.0.0.html and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13855 for more information.